Decal geometry not appearing on instancedmesh in Three.js
I have an instanced mesh set up in Three.js as follows:
const numPoints = 100;
const points = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i < numPoints; i++) {
    const randomX = getRandomInteger(1, 6);
    const randomY = getRandomInteger(2, 8);
    const randomZ = getRandomInteger(1, 9);
    const pos = new THREE.Vector3(randomX, randomY, randomZ);
    points.push(pos);
}
const instanceGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
const instanceMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(0xff0000) });
const instancedMesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh(instanceGeometry, instanceMaterial, numPoints);

const dummy = new THREE.Object3D();

scene.add(instancedMesh);
for (let i = 0 ; i < points.length; i++) {
    dummy.position.set(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
    dummy.updateMatrix();
    instancedMesh.setMatrixAt(i, dummy.matrix);
}

With a basic raycaster that casts a ray from the camera, I am looking to find which instance of the instanced mesh has been clicked. And based on the position of this click, I want to apply a decal on that instance at that position. The following is the code that I have set up:
const decals = [];

document.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => {
    const windowX = e.clientX;
    const windowY = e.clientY;
    const ndcX = ((windowX / window.innerWidth) * 2) - 1;
    const ndcY = -((windowY / window.innerHeight) * 2) + 1;
    
    raycaster.setFromCamera(new THREE.Vector2(ndcX, ndcY), camera);
    const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
    console.log(intersections);
    if (intersections.length) {
        // get the first object you intersect with
        const intersectedInstance = intersections[0];
        const { face: { normal }, object, point, instanceId } = intersectedInstance;
        
        // get the instance transformation matrix 
        const instanceMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        instancedMesh.getMatrixAt(instanceId, instanceMatrix);

        const worldInstanceMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        worldInstanceMatrix.multiplyMatrices(instanceMatrix, instancedMesh.matrixWorld);
        ///

        const dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
        const n = normal.clone();
        n.transformDirection( worldInstanceMatrix );
        n.add(point.clone());

        dummy.position.copy( point.clone() );
        dummy.lookAt( n );

        const  size = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1.0);
        
        const decalGeometry = new DecalGeometry( object, point, dummy.rotation, size ); 
        const decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, depthWrite: false, polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: - 4, depthTest: false} );
                        
        const decal = new THREE.Mesh( decalGeometry, decalMaterial );
        decals.push(decal);
        decal.renderOrder = decals.length;

        scene.add(decal);
        

    }


});

However, the decal geometries just won't show up. Any pointers as to where this is going wrong? On consoling the scene's children, the decal meshes are added, but there's nothing that shows up on the canvas. Any help and guidance will be hugely appreciated!
Note: Instead of deriving the instances transformation matrix, I have tried to directly apply the orientation argument as :
 const orientation = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), // Default orientation
            normal
        );

but, to no avail.
